# SimpleDateFormat parse exception for Time

Tags: java, android, parsing, time, error-handling

```
DateFormat FORMAT_TIME_AM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");//works
```

If I use this code, everything works fine, but when I insert an "a" to display the AM/PM in the end, a parsing exception is raised.

```
DateFormat FORMAT_TIME_AM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");//does not works
```

Here is the error:

```
com.finalagenda W/System.err java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2:11" (at offset 4) com.finalagenda W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: please show the code where you are using the DateFormat

Comment: Okay Mike, that might be a problem, do you have any idea how can I input the AM/PM string with SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 1):

In `SimpleDateFormat`, `HH`and `hh` are different. `HH` from 0 to 23 for `24` hours format and `hh` from 1 to 12 (AM/PM) `12` hours format.

```
"HH:mm" -> 13:30 is "hh:mm a" -> 01:30 PM
```

Comment: I know that, but my idea is to be able to display both formats depending on the Android system language.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys I just fixed, just added "AM" to the end of my String time and it automatically changes to "PM" if necessary. Thanks for everything, hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works fine here. Could you please provide part of your code?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    DateFormat FORMAT_TIME_AM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    System.out.println(FORMAT_TIME_AM.format(new Date()));
}
```

Comment: dataHora.setHora(timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                txtDataHora.setText(dataHora.toString());
                picker.cancel(); I try to parse this String, in one format works in another it wont.